# DKIM failure "message has been altered"

Tags: email-server, spf, gmail, dkim, mattermost

**Summary**
I have a Mattermost server which needs to send emails out to users when they sign up, etc. These emails are failing DKIM checks and showing up in users' Gmail as spam.

**Observed behavior**
I have DKIM, SPF and DMARC set up on my mail server. I send email via Gmail using SMTP and these emails pass all checks. When Mattermost sends emails through the same server by SMTP, emails pass SPF but fail DKIM with this message from Gmail:

```
dkim=fail header.i=@example.com header.s=default header.b=YXmrE5yx;
```

Sending email to dkimvalidator.com results in this message for DKIM:

```
Validating Signature
result = fail
Details: message has been altered
```

**Expected behavior**
I am expecting the emails from Mattermost to pass DKIM since they’re under a domain which I thought I'd allowed in my DKIM record.

**Steps to reproduce**
Mattermost Version: 5.19.1
Database Schema Version: 5.19.0
Database: mysql

My Mattermost instance is running on an AWS EC2 instance with an elastic IP, but I've got it set use a subdomain, chat.example.com. This is working for users.

The SMTP settings in Mattermost are:

```
SMTP Server:                          example.com
SMTP Server Port:                     465
Enable SMTP Authentication:           true
SMTP Server Username:                 chat@example.com
Connection Security:                  TLS
Skip Server Certificate Verification: false
Enable Security Alerts:               true
```

These settings are working in the sense that email is successfully sending; it's just going into spam for Gmail.

My DKIM record is:

```
v=DKIM1; k=rsa; c=relaxed/relaxed; d=example.com; p=[DKIM-key redacted]
```

My SPF record is:

```
v=spf1 +mx +a +ipx:xxx:xxx:xx +include:google.com +include:mailgun.org +include:[IP of the EC2 instance] ~all
```

I’m a bit lost on next steps for how to troubleshoot this further; would appreciate your thoughts!

Comment: Are you sure you have the `c=` and `d=` tags in your DNS DKIM record? These are generally found in the signature header, not the DNS record. The error message tells you that a signed header in the email changed in transport. For example, is the sender address you configured in the MM server the same as you see in the email headers you receive? Which are the signed headers (`h=`)? Which email software does your mail server run on?

Comment: Every solve it?

Comment: I swapped to using a Gmail email address and it worked perfectly. I think the problem was my web host's mail server.